# How can I start Oracle Enterprise manager after restarting the Red Hat Server?

Tags: linux, oracle, redhat

I installed Oracle 11g on Red Hat Enterprise server 5.0. First time everything worked well.

After creating dbora script file in /etc/init.d/ and setting all the oracle environmental variables I just restarted the server, then onwards Oracle Enterprise manager is not working

I am not able to open EM on my browser. When I see, emctl status dbconsole - it shows

bash-3.00$ emctl status dbconsole
Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control Release 11.1.0.
Copyright (c) 1996, 2007 Oracle Corporation. All rights reserved.

Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g is not running.
------------------------------------------------------------------

But the agent is running fine =>bash-3.00$ emctl status agent
Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control Release 11.1.0.
Copyright (c) 1996, 2007 Oracle Corporation. All rights reserved.
---------------------------------------------------------------
Agent Version : 11.1.0.0.1
OMS Version : 11.1.0.0.1
Protocol Version : 11.1.0.0.1
Agent Home : /u01/apps/oracle/product/11.1.0/devdb_02_FCC2
Agent binaries : /u01/apps/oracle/product/11.1.0/
Agent Process ID : 983264
Parent Process ID : 741562

Started at : 2009-25-05 10:52:23
Started by user : orcl
Last Reload : 2009-25-05 13:42:41
Last successful upload : (none)
Last attempted upload : (none)
Total Megabytes of XML files uploaded so far : 0.00
Number of XML files pending upload : 0
Size of XML files pending upload(MB) : 0.00
Available disk space on upload filesystem : 28.08%

---

Agent is Running and Ready

When i am trying to start dbconsole, it throughs error:

bash-3.00$emctl start dbconsole

Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control Release 11.1.0.0
Copyright (c) 1996, 2007 Oracle Corporation. All rights reserved.

Starting Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control
............................................................................................. failed.
------------------------------------------------------------------

Please help to resolve this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to re-configure em completely

```
emctl stop dbconsole
emca -repos drop
emca -repos create
emca -deconfig dbcontrol db
emca -config dbcontrol db
```

The best regards

Comment: Yes, I reconfigured the em and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The `emca -deconfig dbcontrol db` command failed while I was reconfiguring, so I skipped that step and ran `emca -config dbcontrol db`. Reconfiguration worked fine and OEM is back up and running.

Answer (score 2):

try

`emctl start dbconsole`

if it does not helps - try to re-configure em

```
emca -config dbcontrol db
```

Answer (score 0):

what we do here is :
su - oracle
and then:
cd /usr/local/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin
./emctl status <-- to check oem is not running
./emctl start dbconsole <-- to start oem

check oracle log files to have more informations about the error

hoping this will help you.

Comment: I tried su - oracle<br> /usr/local/oracle/product/11.1.0/db_1/bin ./emctl status

still it showing 
Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control Release 11.1.0.
Copyright (c) 1996, 2007 Oracle Corporation. All rights reserved.

Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g is not running.
------------------------------------------------------------------<br>

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be related, but if your database is running from `ASM`, check that the `cssd` is running before you call `start` on your `init`-script - or rather make sure that your init script watches the process list and waits until it sees the process before doing anything... (CSSD is the daemon which controls the communication between the database instance and ASM instance).

```
[root@up-edia-db1 ~]# grep cssd /etc/inittab
h1:35:respawn:/etc/init.d/init.cssd run >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null
[root@up-edia-db1 ~]# ps -fu oracle|grep cssd
oracle    3837  3662  0 Mar19 ?        00:02:23 /opt/oracle/product/11.1.0.7/asm/bin/ocssd.bin
```

Another solution is to remove that entry from the `inittab` file and work it into an init script - but when you do any Oracle installation, it will pop it back in there (from memory) - so it becomes high maintenance.  I don't yet know why Oracle insist on putting this in inittab - it's a little painful.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some log files that might help you troubleshoot this issue (from Metalink):

- ORACLE_HOME/hostname_sid/sysman/log/emdb.nohup - contains the standard output from the Console main Java process at each start/exit (dbconsole and agent). It is appended with each new output of the Console main Java process.
- ORACLE_HOME/hostname_sid/sysman/log/emagent.log and emagent.trc - main agent log & trace files
- ORACLE_HOME/hostname_sid/sysman/log/emoms.log and emoms.trc - main management service log & trace files
- ORACLE_HOME/hostname_SID/sysman/log/emdctl.log and emdctl.trc - emctl log & trace files
- ORACLE_HOME/hostname_SID/sysman/log/emagentfetchlet.trc and emagentfetchlet.log - log and trace file for Java Fetchlets

Here's a [discussion](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=709293) on a similar issue.

Also, no underscores should be in the hostname; you shouldn't be using DHCP; nslookup must resolve FQN and reverse lookup must work; IPV6 not yet supported.